# Flink KeyedProcessFunction vs Broadcast state

Tags: apache-flink

i tried to use broadcast state pattern for my flink app, but after some researching i did following:

```
case class MyData(field1: String, field2: String, ts: Long, type: String) // type can be DATA or CONFIG

val stream1: DataStream[MyData] = ... // kinesis queue 1. main Data stream
val stream2: DataStream[MyData] = ... // kinesis queue 2. configuration stream

val union = stream1.union(stream2)
  .keyBy(x => s"${x.field1}_${x.field2}")
  .process(new MyProcessFun)
```

In a `MyProcessFun()` i read the data, and depending on a data coming from a `stream2` i do some logic with the data and emits some elements.
Basically i use a `stream2` like a broadcast state pattern. I do not specifically use broadcast because there is no easy way to access some state i have from `processBroadcastElement`.
Since my config stream is used as an indicator for cleaning state i have in my `MyProcessFun()`.

Streams are `.keyBy` so i do not expect problems with parallelism > 1. This is true?

My question is for what cases is Broadcast still needed?
In what cases is it necessary to use the broadcast pattern?
Since for many cases such functionality can be solved with the help of `.union()`,`.connect() // with no broadcast` + `{Co}ProcessFunction()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to say here.
First of all, it seems You could use the standard `KeyedCoProcess` function to achieve what You are now doing with `union`. It won't really differ much but You can have separate classes for both streams so better type safety and better domain segregation in general.

As for the `broadcast`, the main usecase is when the `control` stream doesn't have key to `keyBy` or simply can't/shouldn't be partitioned.

One example to think of, is that You may have some events generated by external system and You want to apply rules to filter out events that do not fulfill the requirements in the rules. You want to have dynamic rules, so that if user defines a rule it will be immediately used to filter incoming events. For simplicity, let's assume that rules are quite generic applied for all event types (like, if event occured after 5pm given day then it should be filtered or if event lasted more than 5 mins we assume it's invalid). You can't partition such rules, so the solution would be `broadcast`.

Or if you wanted to have a system where You would calculate the total earnings for delivery drivers in real-time. You might have set of additional bonuses (like if the driver does 10 deliveries in an hour there is 5% bonus). You wouldn't want to create a separate set of bonus rules for each driver just so You can `keyBy` it, woudld You ?:)

Comment: I used `.union` because I’m actually combining several streams there. as I understand it is impossible if you use `.connect`.  

that is, in my implementation there are no problems with parallelism greater than 1?  

thanks for the detailed explanation of when to use broadcast.
I understand it as follows, if you want to send general events  to `control` stream that are not tied to any entity in a `data` stream - use broadcast :)

Comment: If the keys are unique then it shouldn't be anny issue when dealing with parallelism in case of union.